# Gatsby translation with transifex

Tags: gatsby, contentful, transifex

I am trying to rebuild our companies website with gatsby. Most of the content for our site is coming from `Contentful` but the translations itself are in `Transifex`.

I am not sure how to integrate all of this. Im using the `gatsby-source-contentful` plugin to pull in data from contentful. 
**What is the proper way to download translations from transifex?**

My idea was to use the transifex API in the `createPages` hook and then pass the locale data as a context variable. And then inside the component file just use `react-intl`.

**Is this the proper way of doing this? or What is a better approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to accomplish this but the one thaf comes to mind is to create the Transifex source plugin yourself. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/create-source-plugin/#create-source-plugin

Once nodes are created with that plugin consider using the node mapping feature. 
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/#mapping-node-types

Comment: Thanks, I created a source plugin as u mentioned. Will look further into mapping node types when i start integrating it.